# SQL condition based on variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have to perform a query and it's where the condition should depend on the variable value.

For example,
if variable **@EventId = 0**
then the condition should be:

```
select * from tbl_event where event_id != @EventId
```

And if variable **@EventId = 10**
then the condition should be:

```
select * from tbl_event where event_id = @EventId
```

I have to do this in the MSSQL database store procedure.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 1: Match @EventId = 0 and event_id != @EventId

Condition 2: Match @EventId = 10 and event_id = @EventId

To fulfill either of these conditions, you need OR operator.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_event 
WHERE (@EventId = 0 AND event_id != @EventId)
  OR (@EventId = 10 AND event_id = @EventId)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working as expected 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl_event 
where Case 
          When @EventId = 0 AND Event_id != 0 THEN 1
          When @EventId = 10 AND Event_id = 10 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

Comment: Fresh but, can we assume @SourabhSingh wants a solution for any positive integer.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes of course, but this is an answer to current question. It can be change if any other update come. Also it give him\her insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
   * 
 FROM 
  tbl_event 
WHERE 
  (
    @EventId = 0 
    AND event_id <> @EventId
  ) 
  OR 
  (
    @EventId = 10 
    AND event_id = @EventId
  )
```